# Can the temperature of the domain in a smoke simulation vary based on height?

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to simulate physically accurate cumulus clouds for a still render and to do so, the temperature of the domain must decrease with height.

I have been told that this may be possible using force fields, but I don't have much experience with them.